# is webviewPanel.onDidChangeViewState not fired when first showing a webview in the visual studio code 1.53.2 version?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the visual studio code 1.52.1 version, the `webviewPanel.onDidChangeViewState` is fired when first showing a webview. However, it does not work in 1.53.2 version.

I was wondering if `webviewPanel.onDidChangeViewState` is not fired anymore when first showing a webview in the visual studio code 1.53.2 version?

But, it seems there are not any specific changes about Webview in [the VSCode Studio Code 1.53.2 released](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53).